# JavaScript Insert html with toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div` which contains a lot of big sized images, and with JavaScript I'm trying to insert this HTML in another `div` with toggle

Please run the code snippet

```js
$(".toggleimages").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();


    var sele = document.querySelector(".bgcontainer");
    var colocontainer = '<div class=container><span class=bgImage><span style="background-image:url(https://www.gamewallpapers.com/img_script/wallpaper_dir/img.php?src=wallpaper_destiny_2_02_2560x1440.jpg&height=450&width=800&fill-to-fit)"></span> </span><span class=bgImage><span style="background-image:url(https://www.gamewallpapers.com/img_script/wallpaper_dir/img.php?src=wallpaper_skull_and_bones_01_2560x1440.jpg&height=450&width=800&fill-to-fit)"></span></span></div>'
    sele.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', colocontainer)

    $(".bgcontainer").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
span{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 140px;
    background-size: cover;
}
.bgcontainer{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="toggleimages"><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>

<div class="bgcontainer"></div>
```

My problem is that the `div` renders each time you toggle the button
How can I prevent the HTML from inserting twice? Or insert and remove on toggle?

Why insert on toggle?: The div is hidden by default, and this is used only IF i wanted to select some background images, So i find it really bad for page speed if all of this big images to render everytime you load the page, instead with javascript I want to insert the html on toggle.

Comment: on click, before update the html.... `sele.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '')` insert the emty html.. so every time your fresh html append...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to clear down the HTML first with: 
`$(sele).html("");`

```js
$(".toggleimages").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();


    var sele = document.querySelector(".bgcontainer");
    $(sele).html("");
    var colocontainer = '<div class=container><span class=bgImage><span style="background-image:url(https://www.gamewallpapers.com/img_script/wallpaper_dir/img.php?src=wallpaper_destiny_2_02_2560x1440.jpg&height=450&width=800&fill-to-fit)"></span> </span><span class=bgImage><span style="background-image:url(https://www.gamewallpapers.com/img_script/wallpaper_dir/img.php?src=wallpaper_skull_and_bones_01_2560x1440.jpg&height=450&width=800&fill-to-fit)"></span></span></div>'
    sele.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', colocontainer)

    $(".bgcontainer").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
span{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 140px;
    background-size: cover;
}
.bgcontainer{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="toggleimages"><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>

<div class="bgcontainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the html before and on click can just do toggle rather setting html each time.

```js
var colocontainer = '<div class=container><span class=bgImage><span style="background-image:url(https://www.gamewallpapers.com/img_script/wallpaper_dir/img.php?src=wallpaper_destiny_2_02_2560x1440.jpg&height=450&width=800&fill-to-fit)"></span> </span><span class=bgImage><span style="background-image:url(https://www.gamewallpapers.com/img_script/wallpaper_dir/img.php?src=wallpaper_skull_and_bones_01_2560x1440.jpg&height=450&width=800&fill-to-fit)"></span></span></div>'
    $(".bgcontainer").html(colocontainer);

$(".toggleimages").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    $(".bgcontainer").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
span{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 140px;
    background-size: cover;
}
.bgcontainer{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="toggleimages"><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>

<div class="bgcontainer"></div>
```

If you want to load image on click only then just move `$(".bgcontainer").html(colocontainer);` line in `click` after `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Sorry, I need the HTML to insert on toggle only and not every time someone loads my website, this is bad for page speed, I explained in post why, Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check `.container` using `length`. Check updated snippet for this.

```js
$(".toggleimages").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!$(".bgcontainer .container").length){

    var sele = document.querySelector(".bgcontainer");
    var colocontainer = '<div class=container><span class=bgImage><span style="background-image:url(https://www.gamewallpapers.com/img_script/wallpaper_dir/img.php?src=wallpaper_destiny_2_02_2560x1440.jpg&height=450&width=800&fill-to-fit)"></span> </span><span class=bgImage><span style="background-image:url(https://www.gamewallpapers.com/img_script/wallpaper_dir/img.php?src=wallpaper_skull_and_bones_01_2560x1440.jpg&height=450&width=800&fill-to-fit)"></span></span></div>'
    sele.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', colocontainer)
}
    $(".bgcontainer").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
span{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 140px;
    background-size: cover;
}
.bgcontainer{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="toggleimages"><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>

<div class="bgcontainer"></div>
```

> or you can empty old `.container` div

```js
$(".toggleimages").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   
$(".bgcontainer").empty();
    var sele = document.querySelector(".bgcontainer");
    var colocontainer = '<div class=container><span class=bgImage><span style="background-image:url(https://www.gamewallpapers.com/img_script/wallpaper_dir/img.php?src=wallpaper_destiny_2_02_2560x1440.jpg&height=450&width=800&fill-to-fit)"></span> </span><span class=bgImage><span style="background-image:url(https://www.gamewallpapers.com/img_script/wallpaper_dir/img.php?src=wallpaper_skull_and_bones_01_2560x1440.jpg&height=450&width=800&fill-to-fit)"></span></span></div>'
    sele.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', colocontainer)

    $(".bgcontainer").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
span{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 140px;
    background-size: cover;
}
.bgcontainer{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="toggleimages"><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>

<div class="bgcontainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the '.container' div is already present in the div '.bgcontainer' and insert if not present. Please find the modified code snippet below

```js
$(".toggleimages").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    

    var sele = document.querySelector(".bgcontainer");
    var colocontainer = '<div class=container><span class=bgImage><span style="background-image:url(https://www.gamewallpapers.com/img_script/wallpaper_dir/img.php?src=wallpaper_destiny_2_02_2560x1440.jpg&height=450&width=800&fill-to-fit)"></span> </span><span class=bgImage><span style="background-image:url(https://www.gamewallpapers.com/img_script/wallpaper_dir/img.php?src=wallpaper_skull_and_bones_01_2560x1440.jpg&height=450&width=800&fill-to-fit)"></span></span></div>'
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('container') && document.getElementsByClassName('container').length ==0)
    sele.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', colocontainer)

    $(".bgcontainer").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
span{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 140px;
    background-size: cover;
}
.bgcontainer{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="toggleimages"><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>

<div class="bgcontainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `.empty()` it before insertion:

```
$(".toggleimages").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var sele = document.querySelector(".bgcontainer");
    var colocontainer = '<div class=container><span class=bgImage><span style="background-image:url(https://www.gamewallpapers.com/img_script/wallpaper_dir/img.php?src=wallpaper_destiny_2_02_2560x1440.jpg&height=450&width=800&fill-to-fit)"></span> </span><span class=bgImage><span style="background-image:url(https://www.gamewallpapers.com/img_script/wallpaper_dir/img.php?src=wallpaper_skull_and_bones_01_2560x1440.jpg&height=450&width=800&fill-to-fit)"></span></span></div>';

    $(sele).empty();
    sele.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', colocontainer);
    $(sele).slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you load the content before the click function, and then inside the click function only toggle the visibility of that content ? This way the content will be loaded only once, not every time you click

```js
         var sele = document.querySelector(".bgcontainer");
         var colocontainer = '<div class=container><span class=bgImage><span style="background-image:url(https://www.gamewallpapers.com/img_script/wallpaper_dir/img.php?src=wallpaper_destiny_2_02_2560x1440.jpg&height=450&width=800&fill-to-fit)"></span> </span><span class=bgImage><span style="background-image:url(https://www.gamewallpapers.com/img_script/wallpaper_dir/img.php?src=wallpaper_skull_and_bones_01_2560x1440.jpg&height=450&width=800&fill-to-fit)"></span></span></div>'
         sele.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', colocontainer)

         $(".toggleimages").on("click", function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();





           $(".bgcontainer").slideToggle();
         });
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 140px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.bgcontainer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="toggleimages"><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>x</li>

<div class="bgcontainer"></div>
```

Comment: No, because i don't need the images to load every time the page loads, I added some more info to explain in my post, Thank you :)